# Joining tables on non-primary keys and get result something similar to full outer join

Tags: sql, oracle, join

```
Table A                 
Column A    Column B    Column C    Column D            
1           AA          A1          B1          
2           BB          A2          B2          
3           CC          A3          B3          
4           DD          A4          B4          

Table - B                       
Column E    Column F    Column G    Column H            
1           AA          A1          1234            
2           BB          A2          2345            
3           EE          A3          6767            
4           FF          A4          5555            

Result Table [Joining on Column B and Column C with Column C and Column D that are not primary keys]    
Column B    Column C    Column D    Column H            
AA          A1          B1          1234            
BB          A2          B2          2345            
CC          A3          B3          NULL            
DD          A4          B4          NULL            
EE          A3          NULL            6767            
FF          A4          NULL            5555
```

I tried using a full outer join but don't see the expected result. Any ideas?

Comment: Joining on columns b and c to what?

Comment: What is the expected result and what is the actual result? You've given one and not the other.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to join `ColumnB` to `ColumnF` and `ColumnC` to `ColumnG`, you have a couple of options to get to your above results (assuming those are your intended results).

One option would be to use a `UNION`.

```
SELECT A.ColumnB, A.ColumnC, A.ColumnD, B.ColumnH
FROM TableA A
  LEFT JOIN TableB B ON A.ColumnB = B.ColumnF AND A.ColumnC = B.ColumnG
UNION 
SELECT B.ColumnF, B.ColumnG, NULL, B.ColumnH
FROM TableB B
  LEFT  JOIN TableA A ON B.ColumnF = A.ColumnB  AND A.ColumnC = B.ColumnG
WHERE A.ColumnB IS NULL
```

And here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3e31e/1).

Another option would be to use  `COALESCE` and `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(A.ColumnB,B.ColumnF), 
  COALESCE(A.ColumnC,B.ColumnG), A.ColumnD, B.ColumnH
FROM TableA A
  FULL OUTER JOIN TableB B ON A.ColumnB = B.ColumnF AND A.ColumnC = B.ColumnG
```

And more [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3e31e/5).

They both should produce the same results.

**--EDIT**

Assuming your desired results are to remove the NULL values from your output, then something like this should work:

```
SELECT COALESCE(A.ColumnB,B.ColumnF), 
  COALESCE(A.ColumnC,B.ColumnG), 
  COALESCE(A.ColumnD,A2.ColumnD),
  COALESCE(B.ColumnH,B2.ColumnH)
FROM TableA A
  FULL OUTER JOIN TableB B ON A.ColumnB = B.ColumnF AND A.ColumnC = B.ColumnG
  LEFT JOIN TableA A2 ON B.ColumnG = A2.ColumnC
  LEFT JOIN TableB B2 ON A.ColumnC = B2.ColumnG
```

And more fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/32b3e/1

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be rather simplified to do a pre-query of distinct `B/C` and `D/F` combinations... then use that as basis to re-join to `table A` and `B` to get extra columns as needed.  Something like

```
select
      PreQuery.Col1 as ColumnA,
      PreQuery.Col2 as ColumnB,
      A2.ColumnD,
      B2.ColumnH
   from
      ( select distinct 
              a.ColumnB as Col1,
              a.ColumnC as Col2
           from
              TableA a
        UNION
        select 
              b.ColumnF as Col1,
              b.ColumnG as Col2
           from
              TableB b ) PreQuery
      LEFT JOIN TableA A2
         on PreQuery.Col1 = A2.ColumnB
        AND PreQuery.Col2 = A2.ColumnC
      LEFT JOIN TableB B2
         on PreQuery.Col1 = B2.ColumnF
        AND PreQuery.Col2 = B2.ColumnG
```

and if you don't actually want the `NULL` to show, use

```
COALESCE( A2.ColumnD, "" )
```

same with ColumnH